# Ammonium nitrate in fuel-air bombs

Tags: explosives

Are there any fuel-air bombs / thermobaric weapons that utilise ammonium nitrate as a fuel?

I know that BLU-82 is often mistakenly referred to as fuel-air bomb, so I became curious as to whether or not there were any *actual* fuel-air bombs that used ammonium nitrate.

Comment: Ammonium nitrate is an oxidizer, not a fuel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explosives that use ammonium nitrate and a fuel are mostly referred to as [ANFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANFO) explosives, you might find more detailled information by using that term.

Most explosives used in military (especially bombs) are based on TNT, mostly in the form of [Tritonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritonal), a mixture of TNT and aluminium powder. Generally, only outdated bombs use ANFO explosives (due to their low price and ease-of-use). (See [BLU-82](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLU-82), which does indeed use ammonium nitrate)

ANFO explosives are rather used in an industrial context, especially [mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANFO#Industrial_use).

In the common mixture of ammonium nitrate with nitromethane [(ANNM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANFO#ANNM), no oxygen from the air is needed to sustain the explosion:

$\ce{3NH4NO3 + 2CH3NO2 -> 4N2 + 2CO2 + 9H2O}$

Since ANFO explosives carry their oxygen with them by definition (the ammonium nitrate molecule contains 3 oxygen atoms), they do not need oxygen from the surroundings and are therefore not thermobaric or fuel.air weapons.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any FAE devices using ammonium nitrate as a fuel.

Oxirane is rather common, the thermobaric hellfire (AGM-114N) uses aluminium dust and the original WWII designs of Mario Zippermayr's anti-aircraft device used coal dust.